# Magento 2.3 menu static block as dropdown

Tags: menu, magento2.3, topmenu

Currently in Magento 2.3 the dropdown menu only can show the subcategories. I want to change this so that the subcategories are not displayed but only a specific static block.

Inside that block I want to create my own navigation with subcategories and other content.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you want to remove the dropdown element completely then use `<referenceBlock remove="true" name="navigation.sections" />` in your theme's `default.xml` file. In the same file you can add a static block via `<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block"> ...` and passing the identifier as an argument.

Comment: @user7290573 Thanks for the reply! I found the remove element indeed, but I do not know how to add the static block with passing the identifier. Can you show me the entire code for this?

Comment: Posted the code as an answer - let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work when placed inside your theme's `default.xml` layout file:

```
<!-- Insert a custom container to the page wrapper -->
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">

    <!-- The custom <header> container is called my-header -->
    <container name="my-header" before="-" htmlTag="header" htmlId="my-header">

        <!-- Add a static block with an identifier of header_links_block -->
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header_links_block">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header_links_block</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

    </container>

</referenceContainer>

<!-- Remove default navigation section -->
<referenceBlock remove="true" name="navigation.sections" />
```

Comment: Many thanks! The only problem is that we now can not add a custom block as dropdown to each category. Any idea to how to edit this, so that we can add a custom block to each category as dropdown?

Comment: @HenkZ I don't fully understand what you mean. Let's say you're viewing a category called "Men's Hoodies & Sweatshirts" - would you want it to automatically show a custom block called `mens-hoodies-sweatshirts` (for example) and so on for each category?

Comment: Thanks! What I need is just something like a mega menu module, but I do not want all unnecessary code, because we do not use a lot of the options. The only thing is that we want to create 5 top categories, when hover in the menu it will show a dropdown. And that dropdown should be a unique custom block, so that we can add our own links and images etc.

Comment: @HenkZ why can't you just add your custom content to the `header_links_block` block? I still don't understand what you mean exactly - can you link to an example?

Answer (score 0):

Was this figured out yet. 
I'm trying to do the same: Replace the category dropdown with a drop down that, when hovered, will show custom block in a dropdown, like the subcategory does.

Comment: Nope I still have not found a solution to this problem. Do you have found a solution?